# Memcpy C++ alternative

Tags: c++, input, sdl-2

I am using the library [SDL2](https://libsdl.org) on Windows 10 with the MSVC (aka. Visual C++) compiler for a personal project. I am having troubles while trying to handle input.
The code is as follows and it's origin is from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E13yeArUHN0):

```
// InputManager.hpp

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class InputManager
{
public:
    static InputManager *This();
    // ... 

private:
    InputManager(); // this is a singleton class.

    const Uint8* currentkb;
    Uint8* prevkb;
    int keyLength;
    // ...
};
```

```
// InpuManager.cpp

InputManager* InputManager::This()
{
    static InputManager ret;
    return ret;
}

InputManager::InputManager()
{
    currentkb = SDL_GetKeyboardState(&keyLength);
    prevkb = new Uint8[keyLength];
    memcpy(prevkb, currentkb, keylength);
}

// ...
```

I want to do the copying of the data from currentkb to prevkb without using memcpy, and possibly , use a more "C++ friendly" (that works in C++ but not in C) and safe way.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and its `assign` function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pointers are RandomAccessIterator and you have the number of available consecutive elements, you can use the InputIterator ctor of [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
const auto * const currentkb = SDL_GetKeyboardState(&keyLength);
std::vector<std::uint8_t> prevkb(currentkb, currentkb + keyLength);
```

For existing variables you can also use [`std::vector<T>::assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign):

```
prevkb.assign(currentkb, currentkb + keyLength);
```

Or use move assignment: (It probably won’t make a difference in the end)

```
prevkb = decltype(prevkb)(currentkb, currentkb + keyLength);
```

Comment: You seem to have conflicting declarations for `currentkb` here -- perhaps some of them should be `prevkb`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest change is to use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) instead of `memcpy`. They're type-safe and with trivially copyable data types they will probably compile to a `memcpy` or `memmove` call and get the speed benefit of those highly-optimized functions.

```
std::copy(currentkb, currentkb + keylength, prevkb);
```

or

```
std::copy_n(currentkb, keylength, prevkb);
```